# Swift / Enable Editing Mode in View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, edit

Because of UI elements, I created View Controller
with a TableView inside.
But I can't enable editing mode. I tried several methods without Solution.
But with using TableView Controller there are no problems.

What I tried:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
 super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            // Action to delete data
        }
    }
```

Where can be the problem?

Comment: but this is for tableview Controller not viewcontroller

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You forgot to put the table view in editing mode:

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    self.tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
```

I'm assuming you have a `tableView` property. Adjust as needed.

Some other things you may want to do to emulate a `UITableViewController`:

1. In `viewWillAppear` you should deselect the currently selected row in the table view.
2. In `viewDidAppear` you should flash the scrollbars of the table view.