# how to add a delete button in a table view cell in IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on tableview cell in swift and I want to delete a particular cell with a delete button . I have tried taking button through `storyboard` but it does not works.

What can I do for it ?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30688540/656600

Answer (score 0):

try this method for tableview ::

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        if editingStyle == .Delete
        {
         //code for delete
        }
    }
```